# Find out users who do not have a particular role

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a set of DB roles defined in my oracle database. say

- VIEWER- Select only
- UPDATER - select & update only
- EDITOR - select & delete only
- BYPASSER- select & insert only

And I have a some  users who has been granted all the roles and some who do not
.Either way, all the users will be having at least one of the mentioned role granted to them.

My goal is to identify all the users who does not have say, UPDATER and BYPASSER role

```
select grantee from dba_role_privs 
where granted_role not in ('UPDATER','BYPASSER')
```

The above code is listing all the users available in DB as all the users are having at least one of the role granted to them.

How should I reframe the query to get the desired output ?

Comment: please provide sample data

Comment: Somehow GROUP BY  grantee HAViNG  SUM(CASE WHEN granted_rol = ‘role’ THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0 AND SUM(CASE ... END) = 0 comes to mind.. But it is hard to suggest a answer without knowing example data and expected result i advice you to read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Should a user with UPDATER  but not BYPASSER be returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `group by grantee` and put a condition in `HAVING` clause:

```
select grantee 
from dba_role_privs
group by grantee
having sum(
  case 
    when granted_role in ('UPDATER','BYPASSER') then 1
    else 0
  end 
) < 2
```

This will return uses who don't have both `'UPDATER'` and `'BYPASSER'` roles.
If you want the users who don't have either of these roles, change the condition to `= 0` instead of `< 2`.

Comment: Just what I was looking for.  I actually need users who don't have either role. So condition '=0' will do.